# different ways of instantiation

Tags: c++, pointers, instantiation

I'm curious, what is a difference between:

```
Trie* trie = new Trie();
```

and

```
Trie trie;
```

I guess that whereas in the first case `trie` is just a pointer to the object in the second case `trie` *is* the object itself. But what is the difference in practice? When to use which way?

Or, is some on these a "preferred" style?

Comment: It's very important that you not think of this as being a matter of style.  It is not.  It is a matter of deep design intention.  You must understand the reasons for each in great depth to make a valid choice.  And your choices must be matched to the type of object, its uses, etc.  There is no one right answer, but only the best you can do for a given set of circumstances.  All choices have various drawbacks or trade-offs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows you need to start learning C++ seriously from a book. The answer to this question will be very long as these two are very different.

In short however, these are some clues for you:

```
Trie* trie = new Trie();
```

Allocates memory on the heap, you get a pointer to the allocated memory and you need to `delete` it when you are done with it.

```
Trie trie;
```

Allocates `trie` on stack and the object is destroyed as soon as its scope ends.

You use the first one if you need an object to be alive through different scopes, and the second if the object is only needed in a specific scope.

The first one has run time cost while the second one has none (or very very little).

With the first one, you can allocate all the memory you want (as much RAM as you have), while with the second you are bound by the size of the stack.

#### Edit: Answer to your first comment

The stack is allocated *by the operating system* when the program is loaded. The compiler does not assume any particular size for the stack and indeed, upon every function call or in general when you enter e new scope, simply goes and writes further on the stack. If you have recursive functions that go too deep, indeed you will get a segmentation fault (access violation) error.

Heap on the other hand is the whole pool of memory the computer had, and the operating system manages. A call to `new` *requests* memory from the operating system. If there is not enough memory, the operating system may reject the request and you will get a `NULL` (Side note: after every `new` you must check whether the result is `NULL` or not. If it is `NULL`, you should handle this failing case. Otherwise your program will crash). Likewise, when don't need the memory again, you **must** `delete` it. Note also that `delete` calls the destructor of your object and thus is in fact crucial for a sane program.

Comment: thanks. One more question: the main difference between stack and heap is that data on the stack are invalidated the moment a particular scope ends whereas data on the scope are there until I delete them. And size of the stack is limited(and set at a compilation time). Right?

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely about lifetime.

If the lifetime is tied to the lifetime of its declaration, then the second one makes most sense.  If the lifetime is longer, then you usually use the former (though you're usually better off using a shared_ptr of some sort to ensure no memory leaks).

e.g. if I need a Trie for the duration of a function or method:

```
void MyFun()
{
  Trie trie;
  // use my trie...
  ...
  // now trie (instance of Trie) dies - no leaks, can't be accessed by anyone else, better not have given out pointers or references to it that exist beyond this point!!!
}
```

But maybe I have a class that is to hold a Trie (and therefore that instance is to be tied to the same lifecycle as it's owning class instance):

```
class C
{
public:
    C() : trie(args..) { }
private:
    Trie trie;   // <- this instance will live exactly as long as it's instance of C does
};
```

However, if you need instances of Trie to exist for arbitrary duration, or have variable numbers of consumers, then you use pointers (or if Trie is expensive to copy, or holds external resources or fragile state).  But this is a much more complex discussion, and should be handled by a longer treatise on basic C++.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pointer to the `Trie` class: `Tire *trie;` This pointer points to a undefined location in memory because you have not assigned it a memory address by using new. If you try to use a undefined pointer it will cause an exception and make your program end (because a undefined pointer doesn't point to anything). When you use the statement: `Trie *trie = new Trie();`you're asking the computer to allocate enough bytes to hold one `Trie` object on the heap and return that memory address to the pointer `trie`. When you use the statement `Trie trie;`you're asking the computer to allocate enough bytes to hold one `Trie` object on the stack.